# Stream buffering issue

Tags: c

The mod_rewrite [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#prg) states that it is a strict requirement to disable in(out)put buffering in a rewrite program.

Keeping that in mind I've written a simple program (I do know that it lacks the EOF check but this is not an issue and it saves one condition check per loop):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main ( void )
{
    setvbuf(stdin,NULL,_IONBF,0);
    setvbuf(stdout,NULL,_IONBF,0);
    int character;
    while ( 42 )
    {
        character = getchar();
        if ( character == '-' )
        {
            character = '_';
        }
        putchar(character);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After making some measurements I was shocked - it was over 9,000 times slower than the demo Perl script provided by the documentation:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
    $| = 1; # Turn off I/O buffering
    while (<STDIN>) {
        s/-/_/g; # Replace dashes with underscores
        print $_;
    }
```

Now I have two related questions:

**Question 1.** I believe that the streams may be line buffered since Apache sends a new line after each path. Am I correct? Switching my program to

```
setvbuf(stdin,NULL,_IOLBF,4200);

setvbuf(stdout,NULL,_IOLBF,4200);
```

makes it **twice** as fast as Perl one. This should not hit Apache's performance, should it?

**Question 2.** How can one write a program in C which will use unbuffered streams (like Perl one) and will perform as fast as Perl one?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0)`?

Comment: @FatalError fixed the typo thanks. Without buffering the program is extremely slow. But I believe that buffering may be used without problem in this case.

Comment: What is with the 42s?

Comment: @DrC 42 keeps the while loop running since it evaluates to `true` also 42 hundreds of bytes are allocated to stream buffers.

Answer (score 2):

Question 1:  You would have to look at the code.  It could be line buffered, it could be using fflush at the end of each request (or block of requests), or it could be using write calls with a larger buffer.  In any case, it won't be doing per-character I/O which is what your program is doing.

Question 2:  I suspect the main issue is on output.  If you were to assemble the entire result in a buffer and write that out as one call, then you would be faster.  However, that just means you are doing the line buffering instead of having the library take care of it for you.  The key is that with no buffering, each output call results in a system call - that is very high overhead.  In theory, the same concept holds true on input but I'm not sure the implementation wouldn't notice the available characters and buffer them in any case.  Same workaround though - read a larger buffer and then take it apart yourself.

Personally, I'd avoid all the setvbuf stuff and just do an fflush at the end of each request.

Comment: But why is unbuffered Perl script is so fast? I don't know Perl well but I suspect that it is in fact NOT unbuffered. There is only one call to `$| = 1;` which disables buffering only for one stream.

Comment: I thought that it would be more performant to check each character one by one than reading them by chunks and then scanning those chunks to replace characters. I was probably mistaking...

Comment: I'm not actually familiar with $| so can't say much about its exact semantics.  I strongly suspect the script is operating line buffered because it is always reading and writing full lines.

Comment: In this case, it will be all about the number of system calls - processing by the line does many fewer of them.

Answer (score 0):

When writing to a terminal, `stdout` is flushed after every line. This way you can always see the output right away. When writing to a file or, as in your case a pipe, this automatic flush is disabled. Usually in those cases performance is more important.

This causes problems when processes have to interact with each other. One program writes something. It's not sent instantly but stored in a buffer. Second program waits for that data. First program waits for more data from second program resulting in a deadlock.

To avoid this, you need to flush all the output before waiting for additional input. Simple `fflusuh(stdout)` before every **read** operation should be enough. This is actually what `$|=1` does in Perl. Nothing needs to be done with `stdin`.

If performance is critical and you need to operate only on single bytes. Read and write data in big chunks using unbuffered [read](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read)/[write](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write). For example:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    char buf[1024];
    while(1) {
        int len = read(0,buf,sizeof(buf));
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++) {
            if ( buf[i] == '-' ) {
                buf[i] = '_';
            }
        }
        write(1,buf,len);
    }
}
```